# Enable HAProxy logging in Amazon Gentoo

Tags: amazon-ec2, logging, haproxy, gentoo

I am attempting to enable HAProxy logging in Gentoo 1.12.11.1 on an Amazon EC2 Server (managed through EngineYard).

I have modified the syslog.conf file as follows:

```
local0.*                -/var/log/haproxy.log
```

I have also modified the haproxy.cfg file to include

```
log   127.0.0.1       local0
```

under the global settings.

I have restarted both daemons and the log file was created at the specified place. However HAProxy is still unable to write to the file. I assume this is because Syslog isn't configured to accept TCP/UDP connections. According to http://linuxadminzone.com/enable-or-fix-logging-for-haproxy-load-balancer/ I need to pass the -r flag to enable this functionality. Unfortunately I cannot figure out where on this distro to set that flag.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find that in the `/etc/conf.d/sysklogd` file:

```
SYSLOGD="-m 0 -r"
```